# How to match digits between strings not between numbers

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to write a regular expression that matches with digits that does not have integer on left or right side? If we have these strings:

```
a20c
 20c
.20c
a20-
120
```

It should match the four first, but not the last one.

Comment: Any integer matching one will do it

Comment: `/^\d+$/` should do the trick

Comment: Do you need to catch only the middle two digits?

Comment: Yes @krzyk , i just need to match that specific digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex patterns will match text that has the `20` somewhere in the middle and of which no other number is touching the `20`. This could occur anywhere in the text, therefore matching `DM11 20-B` but not `DM1120-B`.

```
[^0-9]20[^0-9]
```

Or a little more condensed:

```
\D20\D
```

Comment: It can be anywhere but not between the any other digit means 20 does not have any other integer on just left or right side

Comment: 20 be anywhere but not between the any other digit means 20 does not have any other integer on just left or right side. For eg. it should match with DM11 20-B but not with DM1120-B

Comment: I have updated my answer to take into account those new test cases

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^\D{1}\d+\D{1}$`

Olso you can test your regex here:
https://regex101.com/r/nU4jL1/2

Comment: 20 be anywhere but not between the any other digit means 20 does not have any other integer on just left or right side.
For eg. it should match with DM11 20-B

Comment: Dunno if i understood right, but try this `\D{1}20+\D{1}` https://regex101.com/r/nU4jL1/3, this works with your example DM11 20-B

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 lookarounds to make sure your digits are surrounded by non-digits:

```
(?<=\D)\d+|\d+(?=\D)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG0cQ1/1)

Comment: can you please write example for number 20?